# Recreate Facebook comment box or Live Stream with Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

Been searching all over for something tangible on this topic.

The basic issue is this: The site is fully responsive but none of its hundreds of facebook social plugins are. This means that when the site scales up or down to accommodate and given browser size all the facebook widgets stay fixed, and thereby break the grid.

So the obvious solution is to not use any of facebook's pre made widgets for live chat (Live Stream plugin) or comments (comments plugin) but instead build our own widgets and make them responsive. But. I cannot find ANY information on if it is possbile to recreate for example the facebook comments plugin using the Graph API. Ideally I'd like the same functionality as is already present in the pre made widgets.

Any information that could lead me in the right direction here would be deeply appreciated!

Best
Fredrik